# Kotlin native protobuf problems

Tags: gradle, kotlin, kotlin-native

Whenever I try to run gradle task `runDebugExecutableLinux`, the following happens...

```
    ./gradlew runDebugExecutableLinux -Dorg.gradle.java.home=$JAVA_HOME

> Configure project :
Kotlin Multiplatform Projects are an experimental feature.

> Task :linkDebugExecutableLinux FAILED
e: Compilation failed: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.

 * Source files: Main.kt
 * Compiler version info: Konan: 1.3.1 / Kotlin: 1.3.40
 * Output kind: PROGRAM

e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidWireType(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:99)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.protobuf.CodedInputStream.skipField(CodedInputStream.java:262)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.parseUnknownField(GeneratedMessageLite.java:73)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.metadata.konan.KonanProtoBuf$LinkDataPackageFragment.<init>(KonanProtoBuf.java:1074)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.metadata.konan.KonanProtoBuf$LinkDataPackageFragment.<init>(KonanProtoBuf.java:1033)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.metadata.konan.KonanProtoBuf$LinkDataPackageFragment$1.parsePartialFrom(KonanProtoBuf.java:1167)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.metadata.konan.KonanProtoBuf$LinkDataPackageFragment$1.parsePartialFrom(KonanProtoBuf.java:1162)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:137)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:168)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:180)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.metadata.konan.KonanProtoBuf$LinkDataPackageFragment.parseFrom(KonanProtoBuf.java:1453)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.konan.KonanDeserializationUtilsKt.parsePackageFragment(KonanDeserializationUtils.kt:6)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.konan.KonanPackageFragment$protoForNames$2.invoke(KonanPackageFragment.kt:57)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.konan.KonanPackageFragment$protoForNames$2.invoke(KonanPackageFragment.kt:35)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.konan.KonanPackageFragment.getProtoForNames(KonanPackageFragment.kt)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.konan.KonanPackageFragment.getProto(KonanPackageFragment.kt:61)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.konan.KonanPackageFragment$_memberScope$2.invoke(KonanPackageFragment.kt:75)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.konan.KonanPackageFragment$_memberScope$2.invoke(KonanPackageFragment.kt:35)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.konan.KonanPackageFragment.get_memberScope(KonanPackageFragment.kt)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.konan.KonanPackageFragment.getMemberScope(KonanPackageFragment.kt:82)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.konan.KonanPackageFragment.getMemberScope(KonanPackageFragment.kt:35)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.descriptors.impl.LazyPackageViewDescriptorImpl$memberScope$1.invoke(LazyPackageViewDescriptorImpl.kt:46)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.descriptors.impl.LazyPackageViewDescriptorImpl$memberScope$1.invoke(LazyPackageViewDescriptorImpl.kt:30)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:346)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:402)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.LazyScopeAdapter.getWorkerScope(LazyScopeAdapter.kt:23)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.AbstractScopeAdapter.getContributedClassifier(AbstractScopeAdapter.kt:44)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.InteropUtilsKt.getContributedClass(InteropUtils.kt:114)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.InteropUtilsKt.access$getContributedClass(InteropUtils.kt:1)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.InteropBuiltIns.<init>(InteropUtils.kt:33)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.Context$interopBuiltIns$2.invoke(Context.kt:307)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.Context$interopBuiltIns$2.invoke(Context.kt:193)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.Context.getInteropBuiltIns(Context.kt)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.ir.KonanSymbols.<init>(Ir.kt:117)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.ToplevelPhasesKt$psiToIrPhase$1.invoke(ToplevelPhases.kt:123)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.ToplevelPhasesKt$psiToIrPhase$1.invoke(ToplevelPhases.kt)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PhaseBuildersKt$namedOpUnitPhase$1.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:116)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PhaseBuildersKt$namedOpUnitPhase$1.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:114)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.AbstractNamedPhaseWrapper$runBody$1.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:113)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.downlevel(CompilerPhase.kt:23)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.AbstractNamedPhaseWrapper.runBody(CompilerPhase.kt:112)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.AbstractNamedPhaseWrapper.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:92)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:28)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.AbstractNamedPhaseWrapper$runBody$1.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:113)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.downlevel(CompilerPhase.kt:23)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.AbstractNamedPhaseWrapper.runBody(CompilerPhase.kt:112)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.AbstractNamedPhaseWrapper.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:92)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.invokeToplevel(CompilerPhase.kt:41)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.KonanDriverKt.runTopLevelPhases(KonanDriver.kt:27)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native.doExecute(K2Native.kt:79)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native.doExecute(K2Native.kt:34)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:84)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:42)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:104)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:82)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:50)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit(CLITool.kt:215)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMain(CLITool.kt:207)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion$main$1.invoke(K2Native.kt:215)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion$main$1.invoke(K2Native.kt:212)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.konan.util.UtilKt.profileIf(Util.kt:40)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.konan.util.UtilKt.profile(Util.kt:34)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion.main(K2Native.kt:214)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2NativeKt.main(K2Native.kt:296)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.main(main.kt:16)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':linkDebugExecutableLinux'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-10-openjdk/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

I tried fixing it by running it with another Java version, first ran it with jdk8, now with jdk10, but no change, error is still the same.

Here is my build.gradle if it changes anything:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform' version '1.3.41'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.10
targetCompatibility = 1.10
kotlin {
    // For ARM, should be changed to iosArm32 or iosArm64
    // For Linux, should be changed to e.g. linuxX64
    // For MacOS, should be changed to e.g. macosX64
    // For Windows, should be changed to e.g. mingwX64
    linuxX64("linux") {
        binaries {
            executable {
                // Change to specify fully qualified name of your application's entry point:
                entryPoint = 'ymusic.main'
                // Specify command-line arguments, if necessary:
                runTask?.args('')
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        // Note: To enable common source sets please comment out 'kotlin.import.noCommonSourceSets' property
        // in gradle.properties file and re-import your project in IDE.
        linuxMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-native:1.3.0-RC"
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-io-native:0.1.11"
            }
        }
        linuxTest {
        }
        commonMain {

        }
    }
}
```

I don't think it will, as the same thing happens on a new native project, started from scratch.

**EDIT:**
Added output with `--info` flag on a new project

```
11:54:19: Executing task 'runDebugExecutableLinux --info'...

The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 10182). The daemon log file: /home/notyours/.gradle/daemon/4.10/daemon-10182.out.log
Starting 2nd build in daemon [uptime: 1 mins 0.431 secs, performance: 97%, no major garbage collections]
Using 4 worker leases.
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using settings file '/home/notyours/IdeaProjects/test-jdk10/settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file '/home/notyours/IdeaProjects/test-jdk10/build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'test-jdk10']

> Configure project :
Evaluating root project 'test-jdk10' using build file '/home/notyours/IdeaProjects/test-jdk10/build.gradle'.
Kotlin Multiplatform Projects are an experimental feature.
Kotlin/Native distribution: /home/notyours/.konan/kotlin-native-linux-1.3.1
file or directory '/home/notyours/IdeaProjects/test-jdk10/src/commonMain/kotlin', not found
All projects evaluated.
Selected primary task 'runDebugExecutableLinux' from project :
Tasks to be executed: [task ':linkDebugExecutableLinux', task ':runDebugExecutableLinux']
:linkDebugExecutableLinux (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) started.

> Task :linkDebugExecutableLinux
Task ':linkDebugExecutableLinux' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has failed previously.
file or directory '/home/notyours/IdeaProjects/test-jdk10/src/commonMain/kotlin', not found
file or directory '/home/notyours/IdeaProjects/test-jdk10/src/commonMain/kotlin', not found
Run tool: konanc with args: -g -ea -target linux_x64 -p program -o /home/notyours/IdeaProjects/test-jdk10/build/bin/linux/debugExecutable/test-jdk10.kexe -Xmulti-platform /home/notyours/IdeaProjects/test-jdk10/src/linuxMain/kotlin/sample/SampleLinux.kt -entry sample.main
Starting process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/bin/java''. Working directory: /home/notyours/IdeaProjects/test-jdk10 Command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/bin/java -D__idea.mac.env.lock=unlocked -Dawt.toolkit=sun.awt.X11.XToolkit -Dcom.jetbrains.suppressWindowRaise=false -Dfile.encoding.pkg=sun.io -Dfile.separator=/ -Didea.active=true -Didea.cycle.buffer.size=1024 -Didea.dynamic.classpath=false -Didea.fatal.error.notification=disabled -Didea.jre.check=true -Didea.max.content.load.filesize=20000 -Didea.max.intellisense.filesize=2500 -Didea.no.launcher=false -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea2019.1 -Didea.popup.weight=heavy -Didea.registered=true -Didea.version=2019.1.3 -Didea.xdebug.key=-Xdebug -Dio.netty.machineId=28:f0:76:ff:fe:16:65:0e -Dio.netty.processId=3883 -Dio.netty.serviceThreadPrefix=Netty  -Djava.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment -Djava.awt.printerjob=sun.print.PSPrinterJob -Djava.class.path=/home/notyours/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.10-bin/bg6py687nqv2mbe6e1hdtk57h/gradle-4.10/lib/gradle-launcher-4.10.jar -Djava.class.version=52.0 -Djava.ext.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext -Djava.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre -Djava.library.path=/home/notyours/.konan/kotlin-native-linux-1.3.1/konan/nativelib -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.rmi.server.disableHttp=true -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Djava.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment -Djava.runtime.version=1.8.0_212-b10 -Djava.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification -Djava.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation -Djava.specification.version=1.8 -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true -Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.threadFactory=com.intellij.concurrency.IdeaForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory -Djava.vendor=Oracle Corporation -Djava.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/ -Djava.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/ -Djava.version=1.8.0_212 -Djava.vm.info=mixed mode -Djava.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM -Djava.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification -Djava.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation -Djava.vm.specification.version=1.8 -Djava.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation -Djava.vm.version=25.212-b10 -Djavafx.runtime.version=8.0.212-b08 -Djavafx.version=8.0.212 -Djavax.swing.rebaseCssSizeMap=true -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/opt/intellij-idea-ultimate-edition/bin/idea64.vmoptions -Djbre.popupwindow.settype=true -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -Djna.loaded=true -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.platform.library.path=/usr/lib64:/lib64:/usr/lib:/lib:/usr/lib/opencollada:/usr/lib32:/usr/lib/tls:/usr/lib32/tls:/usr/lib/libfakeroot -Djna.tmpdir=/home/notyours/.IntelliJIdea2019.1/system/tmp -Djnidispatch.path=/home/notyours/.IntelliJIdea2019.1/system/tmp/jna5357576498872694060.tmp -Dkonan.home=/home/notyours/.konan/kotlin-native-linux-1.3.1 -Dkotlin.environment.keepalive=true -Dlibrary.jansi.path=/home/notyours/.gradle/native/jansi/1.14/linux64 -Dline.separator=
 -Dlog4j.defaultInitOverride=true -Dorg.jetbrains.kotlin.cliMessageRenderer=GradleStyle -Dos.arch=amd64 -Dos.name=Linux -Dos.version=4.19.59-1-MANJARO -Dpath.separator=: -Dpty4j.preferred.native.folder=/opt/intellij-idea-ultimate-edition/lib/pty4j-native -Dpty4j.tmpdir=/home/notyours/.IntelliJIdea2019.1/system/tmp -Dsun.arch.data.model=64 -Dsun.boot.class.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/classes -Dsun.boot.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/amd64 -Dsun.cpu.endian=little -Dsun.cpu.isalist -Dsun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle -Dsun.java.command=org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 4.10 -Dsun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers -Dsun.os.patch.level=unknown -Dswing.bufferPerWindow=true -Duser.dir=/home/notyours/IdeaProjects/test-jdk10 -Duser.home=/home/notyours -Duser.name=notyours -Duser.timezone=Europe/Ljubljana -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -Xmx3G -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp -Duser.country=GB -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -ea -cp /home/notyours/.konan/kotlin-native-linux-1.3.1/konan/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar:/home/notyours/.konan/kotlin-native-linux-1.3.1/konan/lib/StubGenerator.jar:/home/notyours/.konan/kotlin-native-linux-1.3.1/konan/lib/konan.serializer.jar:/home/notyours/.konan/kotlin-native-linux-1.3.1/konan/lib/Indexer.jar:/home/notyours/.konan/kotlin-native-linux-1.3.1/konan/lib/kotlin-native-shared.jar:/home/notyours/.konan/kotlin-native-linux-1.3.1/konan/lib/kotlin-compiler.jar:/home/notyours/.konan/kotlin-native-linux-1.3.1/konan/lib/Runtime.jar:/home/notyours/.konan/kotlin-native-linux-1.3.1/konan/lib/kotlin-script-runtime.jar:/home/notyours/.konan/kotlin-native-linux-1.3.1/konan/lib/utilities.jar:/home/notyours/.konan/kotlin-native-linux-1.3.1/konan/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar:/home/notyours/.konan/kotlin-native-linux-1.3.1/konan/lib/klib.jar:/home/notyours/.konan/kotlin-native-linux-1.3.1/konan/lib/konan.metadata.jar:/home/notyours/.konan/kotlin-native-linux-1.3.1/konan/lib/protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar:/home/notyours/.konan/kotlin-native-linux-1.3.1/konan/lib/backend.native.jar:/home/notyours/.konan/kotlin-native-linux-1.3.1/konan/lib/version.jar:/home/notyours/.konan/kotlin-native-linux-1.3.1/konan/lib/trove4j.jar org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt konanc @/tmp/konancArgs1404673531652305687.lst
Successfully started process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/bin/java''
e: Compilation failed: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.

 * Source files: SampleLinux.kt
 * Compiler version info: Konan: 1.3.1 / Kotlin: 1.3.40
 * Output kind: PROGRAM

e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidWireType(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.protobuf.CodedInputStream.skipField(CodedInputStream.java:262)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.parseUnknownField(GeneratedMessageLite.java:73)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.metadata.konan.KonanProtoBuf$LinkDataPackageFragment.<init>(KonanProtoBuf.java:1074)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.metadata.konan.KonanProtoBuf$LinkDataPackageFragment.<init>(KonanProtoBuf.java:1033)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.metadata.konan.KonanProtoBuf$LinkDataPackageFragment$1.parsePartialFrom(KonanProtoBuf.java:1167)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.metadata.konan.KonanProtoBuf$LinkDataPackageFragment$1.parsePartialFrom(KonanProtoBuf.java:1162)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:168)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:180)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.metadata.konan.KonanProtoBuf$LinkDataPackageFragment.parseFrom(KonanProtoBuf.java:1453)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.konan.KonanDeserializationUtilsKt.parsePackageFragment(KonanDeserializationUtils.kt:6)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.konan.KonanPackageFragment$protoForNames$2.invoke(KonanPackageFragment.kt:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.konan.KonanPackageFragment$protoForNames$2.invoke(KonanPackageFragment.kt:35)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.konan.KonanPackageFragment.getProtoForNames(KonanPackageFragment.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.konan.KonanPackageFragment.getProto(KonanPackageFragment.kt:61)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.konan.KonanPackageFragment$_memberScope$2.invoke(KonanPackageFragment.kt:75)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.konan.KonanPackageFragment$_memberScope$2.invoke(KonanPackageFragment.kt:35)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.konan.KonanPackageFragment.get_memberScope(KonanPackageFragment.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.konan.KonanPackageFragment.getMemberScope(KonanPackageFragment.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.serialization.konan.KonanPackageFragment.getMemberScope(KonanPackageFragment.kt:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.descriptors.impl.LazyPackageViewDescriptorImpl$memberScope$1.invoke(LazyPackageViewDescriptorImpl.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.descriptors.impl.LazyPackageViewDescriptorImpl$memberScope$1.invoke(LazyPackageViewDescriptorImpl.kt:30)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:346)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:402)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.LazyScopeAdapter.getWorkerScope(LazyScopeAdapter.kt:23)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.AbstractScopeAdapter.getContributedClassifier(AbstractScopeAdapter.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.InteropUtilsKt.getContributedClass(InteropUtils.kt:114)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.InteropUtilsKt.access$getContributedClass(InteropUtils.kt:1)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.InteropBuiltIns.<init>(InteropUtils.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.Context$interopBuiltIns$2.invoke(Context.kt:307)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.Context$interopBuiltIns$2.invoke(Context.kt:193)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.Context.getInteropBuiltIns(Context.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.ir.KonanSymbols.<init>(Ir.kt:117)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.ToplevelPhasesKt$psiToIrPhase$1.invoke(ToplevelPhases.kt:123)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.ToplevelPhasesKt$psiToIrPhase$1.invoke(ToplevelPhases.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PhaseBuildersKt$namedOpUnitPhase$1.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:116)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PhaseBuildersKt$namedOpUnitPhase$1.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:114)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.AbstractNamedPhaseWrapper$runBody$1.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:113)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.downlevel(CompilerPhase.kt:23)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.AbstractNamedPhaseWrapper.runBody(CompilerPhase.kt:112)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.AbstractNamedPhaseWrapper.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:28)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.AbstractNamedPhaseWrapper$runBody$1.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:113)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.downlevel(CompilerPhase.kt:23)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.AbstractNamedPhaseWrapper.runBody(CompilerPhase.kt:112)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.AbstractNamedPhaseWrapper.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.invokeToplevel(CompilerPhase.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.KonanDriverKt.runTopLevelPhases(KonanDriver.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native.doExecute(K2Native.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native.doExecute(K2Native.kt:34)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:104)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:50)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit(CLITool.kt:215)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMain(CLITool.kt:207)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion$main$1.invoke(K2Native.kt:215)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion$main$1.invoke(K2Native.kt:212)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.konan.util.UtilKt.profileIf(Util.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.konan.util.UtilKt.profile(Util.kt:34)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion.main(K2Native.kt:214)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2NativeKt.main(K2Native.kt:296)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.main(main.kt:16)


> Task :linkDebugExecutableLinux FAILED
:linkDebugExecutableLinux (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 2.843 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':linkDebugExecutableLinux'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
11:54:22: Task execution finished 'runDebugExecutableLinux --info'.
```

Comment: This issue looks similar to [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-32356) ticket. Try to delete `/.konan/` directory. I'm confused with the version in the error message.

Comment: That was it! Can you transform your comment into an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue should be gone in the `1.3.41` release. But in this case, something went wrong.

---

In the error message, there is version info:

> - Source files: Main.kt
> - Compiler version info: Konan: 1.3.1 / Kotlin: 1.3.40
> - Output kind: PROGRAM

But as I saw in the build script, you used `1.3.41` version of the multiplatform plugin. So, I recommend checking the `/.konan/` folder, where the compiler is stored. Sometimes it's content can be defected, it's better to delete it manually, and let the Gradle re-download everything.